# Count number of integer and string elements in Array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to count number of integer and string elements in array. My code has some logical error. It shows the number of string incorrect but not showing the number of integer elements.
I am working with string so it skips the first iteration. To execute the first statement i created the `dummy` variable.

```
String dummy;

      int size_of_Array;
        System.out.println("Enter the size of Array:");
        size_of_Array=input.nextInt();

        String [] Array=new String[size_of_Array];
        for(int i=0; i<size_of_Array; i++){
            System.out.print("["+i+"] :");
            dummy=input.next();
            Array[i]=input.nextLine();
        }
        int count1 = 0, count2=0;
        for(int j=0; j<size_of_Array; j++){
            try{
                int k=Integer.parseInt(Array[j]);
                count1++;
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                count2++;
            }
        }
        // numeric and string values after counting
            System.out.println("Numeric: " +count1+ "\nString: " +count2);   
    }
```

Here is the output of code:
Enter the size of Array:
3

```
[0] :abc
[1] :abc
[2] :3
Numeric: 0
String: 3
```

Expected output is:

```
    [0] :abc
    [1] :abc
    [2] :3
    Numeric: 1
    String: 2
```

Comment: Have you looked at the values in your array? I strongly suspect that they're all empty strings.

Comment: You look to be mishandling input as per the linked to dup.

Comment: i don't want to ask about my first iteration

Comment: I want to ask about my logic

Comment: Then add `input.nextLine();` immediately after `size_of_Array=input.nextInt();`, and clean up the acquisition of input within the loop. Only use a single `input.nextLine();` within the loop to get your input into the array. In other words, remove `dummy=input.next();` from inside of the loop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank u so much its working